# How does nginx handle HTTP/1 to HTTP/2 conversion?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http, http2

I just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy) about using nginx as a HTTP/2 server that connects to the web app via HTTP/1 proxy_pass.

However, I am interested in the specifics of what actually goes on with the connections.  In particular, in the case of multiplexing multiple resource requests for HTTP/2, what actually happens on the HTTP/1 connection?  Does nginx make all of the requests for the resources one by one and then combine them?  Or does it open multiple connections to the backend resources?

Additionally, is it still possible to configure the server to send additional files (images, CSS files, etc) along with the main page as a push?